# Take part of a regex search result in Python

Tags: python, regex

I want to read in a header file and output each of the variables that has the form `x = 1.0;` as `double = x;`

At the moment I've got this, which just outputs the whole line:

```
import re 

input = open("file_with_vars.hpp", 'r')
out = open("output.txt", 'w')

for line in input:
    if re.match("(.*) = (\d)", line):
        print >> out, line
```

But I can't work out how to take part of the line and output the variable name and the double string to file.

EDIT:
So now I have

```
for line in cell:
    m = re.search('(.*)\s*=\s*(\d+\.\d+)', line)
    print m.group()
```

But get the error ' AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' '

Comment: Read about grouping. Hint: try `print re.search("(.*) = (\d)", line).groups()`

Comment: you are print the line !!!

Comment: If you got 'NoneType', it means there were no match from your header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `search` instead of `match`

the regex is `.*\s*=\s*\d+\.\d+`

test:

```
import re
y="x=1.0"
m=re.search('(.*)\s*=\s*(\d+\.\d+)',y)
```

The `group` function can be used to extract the matched strings as

```
>>> print m.group()
'x=1.0'
>>> print m.group(1)`
'x'
>>> print m.group(2)
'1.0'
```

EDIT

How to search lines within a file

```
for line in cell:
    try:
        m = re.search('(.*)\s*=\s*(\d+\.\d+)', line)
        print m.group()
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

The `NoneType` error is caused because some lines in the file doesnot match the regex returning a `None` by the `search` method.

The `try except` takes care of the exception.

`pass` a null statement in python

for an input file

```
x=10.2
y=15.3 
z=12.4
w=48
```

creates output as

```
x=10.2
y=15.3 
z=12.4
```

see here `w=48` doesnt match the regex returning `NoneType`, which is safely handled by the `try` block

OR

as Jerry pointed out, an `if` can make that more simple

```
for line in cell:
         m = re.search('\S*\s*=\s*(\d+\.\d+)', line)
         if m:
           print m.group()
```

Comment: This works when I just plug those test values in but when I try to do it for each line in the file I get that NoneType error.

Comment: @Gar You usually just use an `if` to check for a match (or none thereof).

Comment: @Jerry that was so dumb of me. Thanks for that. added in the answer :)

Comment: @Gar glad to hear it worked. Any way i have added another edit, using an `if` statment which is more simpler than my previous code

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the `line` after match .as its possible to exist more than 1 match you can use `re.findall()` , also you need `[\d\.]+` instead of `\d` :

```
for line in input:
    if re.match("(.*) = [\d\.]+", line):
        print re.findall("(.*) = [\d\.]+", line)
```

and about `spaces` after and before of `=` you need to be sure ! if its possible that there are matched like `var=num` you can use `?` after your spaces in your regex pattern: `(.*) ?= ?[\d\.]+`

Answer (score 1):

```
import re 

input = open("file_with_vars.hpp", 'r')
out = open("output.txt", 'w')

for line in input:
    if re.findall("(.*?)\s*=\s*(\d+(?:\.\d*)?)", line):
        print >> out, line
```

Try this.This should work.